# Need regex to match entries that do NOT start with ... and end with

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am looking for a regex that matches two conditions:

1. Entry does not start with either `der`, `die` or `das`
2. Entry ends with `en`, `ern` or `eln`

I got #2 covered by `"\w*en\b|\w*ern\b|\w*eln\b"`

which matches e.g. `kaufen`. But the expression should ignore nouns (entries with `der`, `die` or `das`) at the beginning.

Comment: Give some examples and expected outputs please

Comment: You should give a little more context. Are these assumptions correct: you're treating some kind of german lexical excerpt? You don't want nouns, so entries are not prefixes by the full words `der`, `die`, `das`? You are waiting for single full words ending with `en`, `ern`, `eln`?

Comment: Must `diest` be matched or not?

Answer (score 0):

This regex must be valid too:

```
^(?!der|die|das).*(?:en|ern|eln)$
```

This tool is very usefull: https://regexr.com

Comment: RE2 does not support lookaheads.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), 
 IF(((IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "^(der |die |das )"))<>"") + 
     (IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "(en|ern|eln)$"))="")), , A1:A), ))
```

[image: 0]

### ______________________________________________________________

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), 
 IF(((IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "^(der |die |das )"))<>"") + 
     (IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "(en|ern|eln)$"))    <>"")), , A1:A), ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score -1):

Try with [`negative lookahead`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!der|die|das)(\w*en\b|\w*ern\b|\w*eln\b)$
```

Demo and explaination [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/4d78PM/2).

**Regulex image** (Thanks to @WiktorStribiżew that made me discover it):

[image]

Comment: RE2 does not support lookaheads.